# How to retrieve list of minimum values in each "column" from a list of lists?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

So I have this little function that returns the minimal values in a set of 3 lists, is there a way I can write it to look much nicer? It doesn't seem very Lispy to me, but then again I probably don't know what that means (I'm a lisp noob)
Any tips will be really appreciated.

```
;;;;minimum of 3

(defun minimum-of-3 (list1 list2 list3);returns the minimum value when comparing 3 lists
    (setq minimum-list '())
    (setq mini '())
    (loop for x in list1
            for y in list2
            for z in list3
            do
            (push x mini)
            (push y mini)
            (push z mini)
            (push (apply 'min mini) minimum-list)
            (setq mini '()))

    (reverse minimum-list))
```

Comment: Well, first off all you can remove setqs and wrap it into let, what this function sepose to do if one list is shorter then anores?

Comment: It just ends, it's a comparison of 3 lists of the same length, I'm a noob. I'll wrap it up into a let and see what it looks like. Thanks.

Comment: @coredump I am so confused everytime I see one of your comment ;-)  (did I write this?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

coredump's answer is fine, if you really want to use **loop**, but there's no need to here.  **mapcar** can take multiple list arguments, and **min** takes one or more arguments, so you can just **mapcar** **min** over the lists.

```
(let ((xs '(8 4 1))
      (ys '(3 9 2))
      (zs '(9 2 4)))
  (mapcar 'min xs ys zs))
;=> (3 2 1)
```

Comment: Wrt the edit, I just figured that people trying to solve the same problem would have a better chance of finding it that way.

Comment: Haha, my edit was right ([at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)) one). Even if you rejected it.

Comment: @id256 definitely right on how many args min takes. It's nice that lots of the math operators can take 0 args, returning the identity element for no arguments (e.g. (+) = 0). I think I hit the reject button for some grammatical issue, not because of the technical point. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 4):

If you already using `loop` you don't need anything else here, read about `loop` it's really powerfull

```
(defun minimum-of-3 (list-1 list-2 list-3)
  (loop :for x :in list-1
        :and y :in list-2
        :and z :in list-3
        :collect (min x y z)))

CL-USER> (minimum-of-3 '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 -1))
(1 2 -1)
CL-USER> (minimum-of-3 '(1 2 3) '(4 -5 6) '(7 8 -1))
(1 -5 -1)
CL-USER> (minimum-of-3 '(1 2 3) '(4 -5 6) '(7 8))
(1 -5)
```

Comment: I have only skimmed over the advanced loop part of "The Land of Lisp" I'm currently on the chapter before, I also have "Practical Common Lisp" by Peter Seibel, I'll have a read of both, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Floofk is CL is your first programming language in general consider A gentle introduction to Common Lisp: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'll buy it asap! (Edit: just found it online, I'll see how I get along with that, but reading books on my PC screen has never really worked for me)